# Converting a ready WinForms Application to a ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, clickonce, auto-update

I have a windows forms application that I was working on for a long time and I finished It and want to let it auto update, But... I created the application before I install ClickOnce into my laptop. So the update is not working and when i use

```
if(!ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) 
{ 
    downloadStatus.Text = "Not a ClickOnce application!"; 
}
```

It says that it's not a ClickOnce application.

Comment: Adding ClickOnce to your project configuration and creating a deployment should be possible. You need to use the deployment to install the application at your machine in order for the whole thing to work. It's unclear, what steps you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I have did all the steps required to create a ClickOnce Application, I Just tried creating another application and it worked perfectly but the problem is that this application was created before i install ClickOnce.

Comment: The question is, did you follow all the steps to install your clickonce application? You can create whatever you want as long as you don't replace the installed program it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Yes i did all the steps and i already said i did the exact same thing to the new application and it worked...

Comment: It's just that *"all the steps"* is not *specific*. If you want others to help, you have to explain the specific steps you taken from first to last. Otherwise, noone can explain to you, whether you need to do something different in step 5.

Comment: I created the application,
then i did everything i needed in it,
then i went to the publish settings and i set the application to check for updates before the application starts,
and i set the update location to where i want it to update,
and then all the publish stuff, but still not working